# Gradle error: Could not resolve org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:androidJacocoAgent'.

> Could not resolve org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946.
>     Required by:
>         MYAPP:app:unspecified
>   No cached version of org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of
>   Blockquote

My project's build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 8
        versionName '2.0.6 BETA'
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-adapters:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Are you connected to the internet when you're trying to build/run the application?

Comment: @Luke Melaia Yes of course

Comment: Try adding this statement: `compile group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.7.5.201505241946'` as the first dependency in your dependencies list, so before `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'`.

Comment: @LukeMelaia Thanks it work for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like some dependency needs `org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946` as a dependency, but can't find it for some reason. It can be found in the maven repository side so it does exist. Add this line: `compile group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.7.5.201505241946'` to your dependencies list, so it will look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.7.5.201505241946'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-adapters:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
}
```

This will add the dependency to your project and cut out the middle man so to speak.

Comment: Hi Luke, I think you forgot to add the line to the file in the example code? This solution doesn't work for me but my error is slightly different. This occurs when running the build: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_b0d6a23.Offline

Comment: Thanks @BarryIrvine, I've edited my answer. Your question sounds different from this one. Please open a new question on StackOverflow with all the required details so that the community may better assist you.

Answer (score 6):

For me it happened because android studio actually entered offline mode somehow. After disabling offline mode (Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment-> Gradle-> Offline work) dependency was successfully retrieved.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem because I need VPN to build (the jar repository is private), and VPN was not active.

Answer (score 2):

This might be late to answer but I had the same problem and resolved by disabling offline mode. However, sometime offline mode don't show when you follow these steps
`Settings (preferences on Mac)->Build, Execution, Deployment-> Gradle-> Offline work`.
So what you can do instead is click on the Gradle (on right navigation) and choose the network icon (Toggle offline mode) and disable offline mode.
I hope it helps!